# Accessing Fortran Common Block from C as Struct

Tags: c, struct, fortran, language-interoperability, fortran-common-block

I am trying to define and declare a set of structures in C, then interact with them in fortran before passing them back off to be manipulated in C functions. I understand that interoperability can be achieved through use of c structures and fortran common blocks. I have tried a few methods with no success.

Limitations: Using cvfortran, f77. It is not realistic to convert to newer formats. For C, using MSVS C compiler.

Here's the suggestion from the cvfortran manual, page 618: 
(http://jp.xlsoft.com/documents/intel/cvf/cvf_pg.pdf)

"As an example, suppose your Fortran code has a common block named Really,
as shown:"

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'Really' :: Really
REAL(4) x, y, z(6)
REAL(8) ydbl
COMMON / Really / x, y, z(6), ydbl
```

"You can access this data structure from your C code with the following external
data structure:"

```
#pragma pack(2)
extern struct {
float x, y, z[6];
double ydbl;
} Really;
#pragma pack()
```

Whenever I try this, I get an error for "Unresolved external symbol _Really refereced in function xxx, and it doesn't compile.

Method in CVFortran Manual:

Fortran

```
      PROGRAM MYPROG
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'Really' :: Really
      REAL(4) x, y, z
      COMMON / Really / x, y, z

      INTERFACE 
          SUBROUTINE STRUCTFUN()
cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, ALIAS:'_StructFun' :: STRUCTFUN  ! for calling C functions
          END SUBROUTINE STRUCTFUN 
      END INTERFACE  
      X = 6.
      Y = 5.
      Z = 0.       

      CALL STRUCTFUN() 
      END PROGRAM
```

C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void StructFun(void)
{
    #pragma pack(2)
    extern struct {
    float x, y, z;
    } Really;
    #pragma pack()
    printf("x: %f\n y: %f\n z: %f\n", Really.x, Really.y, Really.z);
    printf("From C \n");

}
```

So then I tried what I have pasted below, in which I define a struct type in the header file, and then try to make it external to c. I should also mention that I am exporting the C function as a dll with a .def file so that it can be called from my fortran module. This gives no errors but returns values of zero for all of my variables.

Sample program:

Fortran

```
      PROGRAM MYPROG
      REAL(4) X,Y,Z
      COMMON / REALLY / X, Y, Z

      INTERFACE 
          SUBROUTINE STRUCTFUN()
cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, ALIAS:'_StructFun' :: STRUCTFUN  ! for calling C functions
          END SUBROUTINE STRUCTFUN 
      END INTERFACE  
      X = 6.
      Y = 5.
      Z = 0.       

      CALL STRUCTFUN() 
      END PROGRAM
```

C function

```
#include "structProg.h"
rtype really_;
void StructFun(void)
{
  printf("x: %f\n y: %f\n z: %f\n", really_.x, really_.y, really_.z);
  printf("From C \n");

}
```

C header file

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} rtype;

extern rtype really_;
extern void StructFun(void);
```

I know it's a stretch to ask this since I'm using an old compiler, but any guidance would be appreciated.

I've also tried a method listed here: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html

Comment: The error message you report does not seem consistent with the code you present.  In particular, the external symbol it complains about is `_Really`, but none of your code references or accesses such a symbol.  Moreover, though your C code access a *similar* symbol `really_`, it also provides a definition of that symbol, and so should not produce such an error.  We're going to have a hard enough time helping you with the old and somewhat idiosyncratic toolchain you're using, so it's even more important than usual for you to present a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'll edit in an example of the first example, sorry about that.

Comment: Your code is not FORTRAN 77 compliant. `REAL(4)` is Fortran 90 syntax and the number 4 is not the same 4 as in `REAL*4` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter The `INTERFACE` keyword is also Fortran 90+.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first comment, but a quick google search shows examples of F77 usage of INTERFACE blocks. After changing the type complaint, I have the same results.

Comment: You mean "programs that look like F77 to you"... INTERFACE is definitely Fortran 90. You can check the standard linked on the tag page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran/info Compaq Visual Fotran does support Fortran 90 and the file extension .f or .f90 does not mater at all for this, it only controls the fiexd vs. free source form.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated question presents a different problem than the original one did.  Now the issue is:

> This gives no errors but returns values of zero for all of my variables.

That's because you are not accessing the common block at all.  Notwithstanding the external declaration of object `really_` in your header file ...

> ```
> extern rtype really_;
> ```

... your .c source contains a *definition* of object `really_` on account of this:

> ```
> rtype really_;
> ```

That's technically a "tentative definition", but there being no definition with an initializer in the same translation unit, the designated object is defined in that TU, and initialized with all members 0.  It should therefore be no surprise that your C code prints out those zeroes.

Moreover, it's unclear why you expect to be able to access the Fortran common block `REALLY` via the name `really_`.  Neither the specific example you've presented from the CVF docs nor the broader text of those docs supports that conclusion.  There being no alias for that block declared on the Fortran side, the docs lead me to expect that it would be accessed on the C side via the all-uppercase version of its name, `REALLY`:

```
extern struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} REALLY;

void StructFun(void) {
    printf("x: %f\n y: %f\n z: %f\n", REALLY.x, REALLY.y, REALLY.z);
    printf("From C \n");
}
```

Note in particular that

- C is case-sensitive, whereas Fortran is not, but the CVF docs seem to indicate that by default it produces uppercase external names for Fortran objects and functions.
- The CVF docs also seem to suggest that it *does not* mangle external names of Fortran objects by adorning them with underscores.  (I haven't read enough to determine whether the same applies to subroutines and functions.)
- Although it is not wrong to do so, it is not necessary to `typedef` a structure type for the common block.  Given the nature of the data, though, it seems more natural to me *not* to do so.
- Note well that my example C code provides only a *declaration* for object `REALLY` (as an external object), not a definition.
- If you wish, you can move the declaration of `REALLY` to a header file.  That would be appropriate if you're going to access it from multiple C translation units, but unnecessary if you're only going to use it in one.
- You can also put a declaration of your function in a header file, but that serves a purpose only if it is called by other C functions defined in other translation units.

Answer (score 0):

I am no guru here, but the error is indicative of that there is not an integrated "C and Fortran" program.

You develop some modules in Fortran and some modules in C (C++). You decide whether it will be a C program (and then has `main` as program entry point) or a Fortran program (and then it has the Fortran program entry point).

You compile the C modules and the Fortran modules with their respective compilers. These deliver .obj or .o files, object files. Finally you link these together to create the executable program.

What you did seems correct. But the "Unresolved external symbol" error is a *linker* error. It means the linker could not find the Fortran Common block in the object modules.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought that questions with these errors should be just closed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381483/very-broad-duplicate-targets

Comment: So in the case with an unresolved external symbol, I would need to compile the fortran first and then link the object files to the C source? What I've been trying is compiling the C source, exporting to a dll, and linking its import library to a fortran source file alongside the fortran compiler.

Comment: Exporting to a DLL is a whole different thing than linking objects produced by Fortran and C into a single executable!